# Jmeter - Looping statement

Tags: java, loops, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I am stuck at one of the situation in jmeter.

I have a CSV file (say) with 10 rows of data "customer_id". This CSV is generated dynamically with "create_customer" sampler request.

In the same thread group, I have another sampler "Add_Credit_card". I need to add 5 credit card to each customer i.e add credit card sampler has to repeat for 1st row of csv for 5 times.

How can I achieve this without using another thread group ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 5 credit cards column in same row, for example:

```
customer_id,creditcard1,creditcard2,creditcard3,creditcard4,creditcard5
1,52330000,52330001,52330002,52330003,52330005,52330005
2,62330000,62330001,62330002,62330003,62330005,62330005
```

Add Counter to loop and save in `CNT` variable (instead of reading CSV) and get current credit card value in loop use [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V):

```
${__V(creditcard${CNT})}
```